# Angular: multiple reciepients of data from endpoint

Tags: angular, rxjs, request, observable, angular2-observables

**Precondition**
I have the following situation:

1. on the backend I have an endpoint, which delivers data. Data is changed very-very seldom.
2. on the frontend I have several components, which need the data from p.1 right after the loading.

**Question** 
How to avoid multiple requests to the backend ( = how to share the result of the first request to all the other callings of a service method).

**Source code - service**

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {

  private ConfigurationUrl: string = 'api/configurations/';
  private httpHeaders: HttpHeaders;
  // ...
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { 
  }
  // ...
  loadCommonSettings(): Observable<CommonSettings> {
    return this.httpClient.get<CommonSettings>(this.ConfigurationUrl + "common");
  }
  // ...
}
```

**Source code - components**

```
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,  private configurationService: ConfigurationService, private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) { 
  }

  isNewDisabled: boolean = true;
  commonSettings: CommonSettings;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCommonSettings();
  }
  //...

  loadCommonSettings() {
    this.configurationService.loadCommonSettings().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.isNewDisabled = false;
        this.commonSettings = res;
      },
      err => {
        this.openErrorDialog("Error", "Error on data loading");
      }
    );
  }
  //...
}
```

**Problem**
Each calling of loadCommonSettings service function fires a new request to the service.

**Supposes**

1. I thought to store data in the service as in the cache, but anyway I have 2 almost simultaneous calls of a service method.
2. Maybe Subjects may help in this situation, but I'm completely not sure about it (because it seems, that Observables are also absolutely Ok for such calls).

Comment: are you familiar with service-workers? if not, read this: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro

Answer (score 1):

Caching is a senseful choice here as you already thought.
In the following an example for your service. You can also use a `BehaviorSubject` instead of the `ReplaySubject` and initialize it with undefined.

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {

  private ConfigurationUrl: string = 'api/configurations/';
  private httpHeaders: HttpHeaders;
  private commonSettings$: Subject<string>;
  
  // ...
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { 
  }
  // ...
  loadCommonSettings(): Observable<string> {
    if (!this.commonSettings$) {
      this.commonSettings$ = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
      this.httpClient.get<string>(this.ConfigurationUrl + "common")
        .subscribe(data => this.commonSettings$.next(data));
    }
    return this.commonSettings$;
  }
  // ...
```

Here only the fist call to the service is starting a http-call. And all calls including the first one are only returning the subject.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works well.
I guess, now I need to learn more about the ReplaySubject.
Thanks a lot again :-)

Answer (score 1):

Below are the solution without using `Subjects`

**Option 1: Using [ShareReplay](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay)**

```
loadCommonSettings(): Observable<CommonSettings> {
    return this.httpClient.get<CommonSettings>(this.ConfigurationUrl + "common").pipe(
        take(1),
        shareReplay(1)
    );
 }
```

**Option 2 :** Using local-Variable to hold result

```
// declare variable to hold cache
private cachedSetting: CommonSettings = null;

loadCommonSettings(): Observable<CommonSettings> {
    // if cachedSetting already available then return same
    if(cachedSetting){
        return of(this.cachedSetting);
    }
    
    return this.httpClient.get<CommonSettings>(this.ConfigurationUrl + "common").pipe(
        tap(response => this.cachedSetting = response)
    );
 }
```

Imports used:

```
import { shareReplay, take, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I've tried both options, and it seems that something is missing. I still see the duplicated request. I'm going to learn more about ReplaySubject and I'll try to fix both solutions. It seems it's pretty similar to the comment of a BozziDev. Thanks again.